# postfix executes command on incomming mail, can't find configuration

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta

i have a postfix instance that should execute a python script on every email to a specific email address. And it is working fine, but i can't locate the configuration for that.

i read that this kind of configuration should be in /etc/aliases like

```
username: "|/your/script"
```

or in ~/.procmailrc like

```
| "/usr/bin/procmail"
```

but there is no file ~/.procmail and my aliases file looks like

```
# See man 5 aliases for format 
postmaster:    root
```

and in my main.cf this file is configured:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

i can find in my /var/log/mail.log i find lines like

```
May 12 11:50:30 Ubuntu-1404 postfix/local[18150]: 3BAAD60008B4: to=<xyz@domain.test.de>, relay=local, delay=0.14, delays=0.05/0/0/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: python /home/xyz/script.py)
```

Can someone help me to find this configuration?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to grep for the python script's name in all of /etc/ and working backwards from there.

It is possible that postfix does not directly run your script. Instead, it may be sending emails to an external verifier (e.g. see the [milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) configurations), and they are running that script.

Other than that, you are really not providing enough information to debug this.

Comment: my grep in etc got no result and in my main.cf are no milters configured. can you give me a hint what infomation you need?

Answer (score 0):

i found it, there is a .forward file in the $MAIL folder and there was the configuration to call the python script